# How to convert String of data to Int variable on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a textdata {} Total number of rows 5.4 million with 3-4 digit integers. I wish to convert them to int on MATLAB.

I tried using `x = str2num(total_data(1:end,:))` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

To return integers , you have to add a prefix and suffix to the string...

```
>> c = '1234567'

c =

1234567

>> class(c)

ans =

char

>> result = str2num(c)

result =

 1234567

>> class(result)

ans =

double

>> result = str2num(['int32(' c ')'])

result =

 1234567

>> class(result)

ans =

int32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = cellfun(@(x)str2double(x), total_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
%Test data
N = 1e4;
textdata = cell(N,1);
for ix = 1:N
    textdata{ix} = num2str(ix);
end

%Convert to integers
dataAsInts = zeros(size(textdata),'int32');
for ix = 1:N
   dataAsInts(ix) = int32(sscanf(textdata{ix},'%d'));
end
```